# C++ overload resolution, conversion operators and const

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, overloading, conversion-operator, function-qualifier

In this case

```
void f(int *);
void f(const int *);
...
int i;
f(&i);
```

the situation is pretty clear - f(int *) gets called which seems right.

However, if I have this (it was done like that by mistake(*) ):

```
class aa
{
public:
    operator bool() const;
    operator char *();
};

void func(bool);

aa a;
func(a);
```

operator char *() gets called. I cannot figure out why would such decision path be better than going to operator bool(). Any ideas?

(*) If const is added to the second operator, the code works as expected, of course.

Comment: The designers of `std::string` had some good reasons for making `c_str()` a named member function instead of a conversion operator.

Comment: Because `operator char*();` is a non-`const` member function.

Comment: `operator bool() { return const_cast<aa const&>(*this); }` also fixes it.

Comment: No, sorry, that would be a terrible fix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because for user-defined conversions with a conversion operator the conversion of the returned type to the destination type (i.e. `char*` to `bool`) is considered **after** the object argument conversion, i.e. the conversion of the object argument `a` to the implicit object parameter.  [over.match.best]/1:

> Given these definitions, a viable function `F1` is defined to be a
>   better function than another viable function `F2` if for all arguments
>   *i*, *ICS*<sub>*i*</sub> *(*`F1`*)* is not a worse conversion sequence than *ICS*<sub>*i*</sub>*(*`F2`*)*, and then
>
> - for some argument *j*, *ICS*<sub>*j*</sub>*(*`F1`*)* is a better conversion sequence than *ICS*<sub>*j*</sub>*(*`F2`*)*, **or, if not that**,
> - the context is an initialization by user-defined conversion (see 8.5, 13.3.1.5, and 13.3.1.6) **and the
>          standard conversion sequence from the return type of `F1` to the destination type (i.e., the type of the
>         entity being initialized) is a better conversion sequence than the standard conversion sequence from
>        the return type of `F2` to the destination type**.

So because the implicit object parameter, which is a reference, is not a `const`-reference for `operator char*`, it is a better match according to the first bullet point.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit [over.match.funcs]/4.

Comment: I don't know why it says that but try it with code and you'll see.

Comment: `auto f = std::bind(&A::f, std::ref(a));` Huh, TIL. I've always passed a pointer.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I think you missed the difference between `this` and the implicit object parameter/argument. The latter solely exists for overload resolution purposes.

Comment: I must have been relying on a `bind` convenience overload.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Whoops, that late edit was a fail. Anyway, this is not what I meant. Implicit object parameters are not existent in code itself (at least not the implicit object parameters in overload resolution).

Comment: My point is that an implicit object parameter is technically part of the "raw" signature of the function. I was hoping to show that you couldn't bind to `A::f` with a reference rather than pointer as the implicit object parameter. The demonstration had nothing to do with the functionality of the `this` pointer.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I suspect you mean another "implicit object parameter" than the one I do, one from another context?

Comment: No.​​​​​​​​​​​​ There is only one implicit object parameter for non-static function members.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit "From another context". In some contexts the implicit object parameter is the `this` pointer. In the context of overload resolution the implicit object parameter is an lvalue reference (or rvalue reference, depending on the ref-qualifier) used as an additional parameter whose arguments conversion sequence is considered just as one from a "normal" parameter.

Comment: _"In some contexts the implicit object parameter is the this pointer."_ For example?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Debugging? It was just an example, anyway. For the standardese, take the definition given in the citation above.

Comment: The standard does not discuss debugging.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Ahh, ok. Then you were just simply wrong as the implicit object parameter defined in there is a reference used for purposes of overload resolution.

Comment: Yes see my third comment above ^^^ :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Ahh, I must have misunderstood you then, my fault. :) Time to get some sleep.

Answer (score 1):

`a` is a non-const instance of `aa` so the non-const conversion operator is a better (exact) match than the const one (requires adding constness), even though the return types don't match as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your "aa" object is not const, so C++ prefers the non-const conversion.

If you make "aa" const, then the const bool() conversion operator will be used.

Comment: I kind of got there myself :) , but still don't understand why would that be a good design choice. Implicitly converting 'this' to const (to enlarge pool of suitable functions) seems like a much smaller thing than converting result.

Comment: That's the point: A function declared const is probably *not* suitable for use on a non-const object.  If it seems like it is, you have either too many or too few "const"s in your code.

Comment: From a more cynical point of view, constness was invented long after the implicit bool/char/int/float/etc conversions were, and by then language designers knew it was important to make their features idiot-proof.

Comment: _"A function declared const is probably not suitable for use on a non-const object."_ I can call `size()` on a non-const `std::string` though.

Comment: Damn, I put the "non" in the wrong place and now it's too late to edit the comment.